# Visual Studio Code - Make Intellisense complete keywords from other file

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

quiet some time, I used Notepad++ for coding my vbs-scripts. Now I'm switching to vscode, for improved syntax highlighting and IntelliSense- features.

Some time ago, I added some "header-file" I want to include to each of my scripts, because I use the same variables in each project and am too lazy to re-type the same text over again. Is there a way to make vscode IntelliSense to recognize the variables I defined in my header-file? If so, how? I would prefer not having build my own snippets, for I still expand my "header-file".

Thank you for your help,

kind regards,
Georg

Comment: That's not possible without a language server implementation. Your "own snippets" won't work either.

Answer (score 1):

The standard method is to modify the c_cpp_properties.json, VS code can do that for you if you prefer, just when you encounter the error (squiggily line under the `#include <generic_header.>`) as such: [include error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eamxJ.png)

Mouse over the error and a pop up will show as such: [error popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tr88o.png)

(Ignore the spanish bit)

Then just use the quick fix hotkey (Ctrl + .) and vscode will do it for you.